# understanding preg_replace (array('/Array\s+\(/', '/\[(\d+)\] => (.*)\n/', '/\[([^\d].*)\]

Tags: php, regex

I have come across a code

```
<?php
define(TRACES_MODE, 'TEXTAREA');//'TEXTAREA' or 'FIREPHP'
$GLOBALS['traces.pre']=array();
function my_array_diff($arr1, $arr2)
         {foreach ($arr1 as $k=>$v)
                  {if (in_array($v, $arr2, true))
                      {unset($arr1[$k]);
                      }
                  }
          return $arr1;
         }
function my_var_export($var, $is_str=false)
         {$rtn=preg_replace(array('/Array\s+\(/', '/\[(\d+)\] => (.*)\n/', '/\[([^\d].*)\] => (.*)\n/'), array('array (', '\1 => \'\2\''."\n", '\'\1\' => \'\2\''."\n"), substr(print_r($var, true), 0, -1));
          $rtn=strtr($rtn, array("=> 'array ('"=>'=> array ('));
          $rtn=strtr($rtn, array(")\n\n"=>")\n"));
          $rtn=strtr($rtn, array("'\n"=>"',\n", ")\n"=>"),\n"));
          $rtn=preg_replace(array('/\n +/e'), array('strtr(\'\0\', array(\'    \'=>\'  \'))'), $rtn);
          $rtn=strtr($rtn, array(" Object',"=>" Object'<-"));
          if ($is_str)
             {return $rtn;
             }
          else
              {echo $rtn;
              }
         }
function tick_handler()
         {$tmp=debug_backtrace();
          $trace=my_array_diff($tmp, $GLOBALS['traces.pre']);
          //echo '<pre>';var_export($trace);echo '</pre>';echo '<br/>'; //for debug diyism_trace.php
          $trace=array_values($trace);
          $GLOBALS['traces.pre']=$tmp;
          if (count($trace)>0 && $trace[0]['file'].'/'.@$tmp[1]['function']!==@$GLOBALS['traces'][count($GLOBALS['traces'])-1]['key']) //filter empty array and rearrange array_values(), because some lines will trigger two tick events per line, for example: 1.last line is "some code;questmark>" 2.error_reporting(...
             {for ($i=count($trace)-1; $i>=0; --$i)
                  {$GLOBALS['traces'][]=$tmp_fb=array_merge(array('key'=>$trace[$i]['file'].'/'.@$tmp[$i+1]['function']), $trace[$i], array('function'=>strtr($trace[$i]['function'], array('tick_handler'=>'CONTINUE')), 'in_function'=>@$tmp[$i+1]['function']));
                   TRACES_MODE==='FIREPHP'?fb(trace_output($tmp_fb), 'diyism_trace:'.++$GLOBALS['diyism_trace_no']):'';
                  }
             }
         }
function trace_output($trace)
         {$trace['in_function']=strtr(@$trace['in_function'], array('require'=>'', 'require_once'=>'', 'include'=>'', 'include_once'=>''));
          $trace['args']=$trace['args']?strtr(preg_replace(array('/\n +/'), array(''), preg_replace(array('/\n  \d+ => /'), array(''), substr(my_var_export($trace['args'], true), 7, -3))), array("\r"=>'\r', "\n"=>'\n')):'';
          return $trace['file'].($trace['in_function']?'/'.$trace['in_function'].'()':'').'/'.$trace['line'].': '.$trace['function'].'('.$trace['args'].')';
         }
function traces_output()
         {echo '<textarea style="width:100%;height:300px;">';
          $GLOBALS['traces']=array_slice($GLOBALS['traces'], 2);//remove registering tick line and requiring 'diyism_trace.php' line
          foreach ($GLOBALS['traces'] as $k=>$trace)
                  {echo htmlentities($k.':'.trace_output($trace)."\n");
                  }
          echo '</textarea>';
         }
register_tick_function('tick_handler');
TRACES_MODE==='TEXTAREA'?register_shutdown_function('traces_output'):'';
?>
```

In above a line

```
$rtn=preg_replace(array('/Array\s+\(/', '/\[(\d+)\] => (.*)\n/', '/\[([^\d].*)\] => (.*)\n/'), array('array (', '\1 => \'\2\''."\n", '\'\1\' => \'\2\''."\n"), substr(print_r($var, true), 0, -1));
```

Is what I am unable to understand.Can some one help me to understand what is happening in this line.

Comment: What you don't understand in particular with this line?

Comment: I am not getting the inside part of regex inside preg_replace_array, I am not clear with what is getting replaced with what inside array() which start with '/Array' then 2 items then a comma and another array('array('',) then substr , which array is replacing what?

Comment: http://ca1.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php Read the 'parameters' section.

Comment: Can you give me an example of line $pattern and $replacement which matches in above code, that is what I am not getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the PHP manual preg_replace can take arrays as parameters for pattern and replacement.

Each pattern is respectively associated with a replacement string. And the string is entirely parsed once per pattern.

With your example:

```
   patterns                                   replacement strings
```

---

```
   /Array\s+\(/                    =>         'array ('
   /\[(\d+)\] => (.*)\n/           =>         '\1 => \'\2\''."\n"
   /\[([^\d].*)\] => (.*)\n/       =>         '\'\1\' => \'\2\''."\n"
```

Note that these multiple search/replace can be simplified a little using this (since the `.*` will stop at newlines):

```
   /Array\s+\(/                    =>         'array ('
   /\[(\d+)] => (.*)/              =>         '\1 => \'\2\''
   /\[([^\d][^]]*)] => (.*)/       =>         '\'\1\' => \'\2\''
```

Comment: yes thanks I was looking for this only, I got confused with the way it was written.Just wanted to know that \1 i.e slash followed by a number is for first pattern match ,2nd pattern match and so on I had some where seen syntax $(1) , $(2) for first match ,2nd match and so on is this in PHP by default that you can use \1,\2 for first match ,2nd match without using a $ sign.

Answer (score 0):

It's taking human readable `print_r()` output (which is not usable code) and replacing it with usable PHP code for an array definition.  I would have just used `var_export()`, but here are simple examples for the 3 array items of patterns and replacements:

```
//lowercase / remove whitespace
Replace: Array       (
With:    array (

//get rid of brackets around key / quote the value
Replace: [1] => whatever
With:     1 => 'whatever'          

//get rid of brackets around key / quote key / quote value
Replace: [something] => whatever
With:    'something' => 'whatever'
```